# SELECT all from two tables where IDs match

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am trying to find all results from my product table that `id`'s exist in another table. I was thinking maybe something like this might work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Product AS p 
JOIN Resource_Downloads_History AS r 
WHERE p.Resource_Id = 3 
  AND r.Resource_Id = 3'`
```

Many thanks if anyone can help point me in the correct direction and tell me what I have done wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Product AS p 
JOIN Resource_Downloads_History AS r
  ON r.Resource_Id = p.Resource_Id
```

Comment: thank you very much this worked great and i have managed to expand it to fit further functionality i was looking at using... thanks again :)

Comment: @CharlieDavey you're welcome. Don't forget to select my answer, that's the best way to thank people on stackoverflow ;)